# Custom Editor for Website in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, wysiwyg, markup

I'm coding my personal website in CodeIgniter, and I wish to integrate a blogging engine as well. Where can I find a WYSIWYG/custom input area which can render markup/HTML, like this one in StackExchange, or even something like the one in Wordpress. Are there any open source WYSIWYG input areas that don't destroy markup and display incorrect HTML?

P.S : Edited to clarify my question

Comment: please Learn terms and clarify,

Stack overflow dose not have a WYSIWYG Editor it has a Custom Editor with a Syntax Highlighter

Comment: My Bad. But even something like Wordpress would work just fine - just for Blogging. Is that a WYSIWYG input area?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript Mootools framework has a WYISWYG you might want to check it out: [mooeditable](http://cheeaun.github.com/mooeditable/)

Answer (score 2):

I disagree **WYSIWYG** will destroy markup,
it works another way round that fix user broken markup

Example of open-source WYSIWYG editors such as,

- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Or markup editor like
 - [Jquery MarkitUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your on about WYISWYG or Syntax Highlighting 
xehna WYISWYG -- is a good one that is desinged to build a full HTML site inside it you would need to control the system a little to allows every thing but it can do it

for syntax highlighting like Stack overflow does codemirror.net